# Get Layout's display name of a Google Presentation Slide via Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am trying to append a new slide to my presentation with a created layout via Google Apps Scripts.

I started a new presentation, created two new layouts, named them as '*BulletDescription*' and '*TextDescription*'.
I can get all the layouts available in the presentation. However, I can't find the layouts which I manually created by their names.

```
function AddNewSlideToPresentation(LayoutType) //LayoutType = 'BulletDescription'
{ 
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById('PresentationID');
  var layouts = presentation.getLayouts();
  var selectedLayout;
  for(var item in layouts)
  {
    Logger.log(layouts[item].getLayoutName());
    if(layouts[item].getLayoutName() == LayoutType)
    {
      selectedLayout = layouts[item];
    }
  }

  var newSlide = presentation.appendSlide(selectedLayout); // this returns an error
}
```

It seems that **.getLayoutName()** function gives us different name as I found on my log;

```
TITLE
SECTION_HEADER
TITLE_AND_BODY
MAIN_POINT
.
.
CUSTOM_1
CUSTOM_2
```

I believe `CUSTOM_1` and `CUSTOM_2` are the ones I created. Is there a way to get display name of the layout via Google Apps Script?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Bumping my head against the same issue (nearly 2 years later!).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386726/how-to-add-a-new-slide-with-new-layout-on-google-slides has good discussion of layout names

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get layout name from [LayoutProperties](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages#layoutproperties):

```
if (layouts[item].layoutProperties.displayName == LayoutType)
{
    // found needed layout..
}
```